# What does "asked silently" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

The phrase, by its very literal meaning, seems a contradiction. If you are silent, you cannot speak and ask the question.

The phrase seems to be [quite popular](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22asked+silently%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks).

Edit: Since there seems to be some confusion, here are some quotes from the link which seem to imply that the words are being spoken out loud -

> ["But he is dead, isn't he?' Madeleine asked, silently](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/No_Such_Thing_as_Immortality/EvJJDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22asked%20silently%22&pg=PT240&printsec=frontcover)

> ["What does the CWO stand for?" he asked silently.](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Kaitlyn_Jones_Surviving_Death/dIXSy1YK4R4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22asked%20silently%22&pg=PA330&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. First, sign languages are full languages in whichit is possible to ask things. Secondly, even without sign languages, you can ask with your eyes, with your hands, with your face, with your whole body.

Comment: @ColinFine: I meant that in the context of the phrase itself not as a general comment. If it  is written " 'But he is dead, isn't he?' Madeleine asked, silently." [emphasis on the quotes inside], then that to me presents a contradiction.

Comment: OK. See randomhead's answer.

Comment: So you've never seen someone who didn't even want to risk whispering something being heard and so not making a sound and simply mouthing it instead, the person to whom its directed having to then make out what they're saying by reading their lips?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples you link at Google Books, it seems they all deal with science fiction or fantasy novels in which a character, for some reason, has the ability to communicate telepathically. So "asked silently" means exactly that—they *thought* the question in their mind instead of *saying* it out loud. This is not something that normal humans in real life can do, and I very much doubt you will find an example in a real-life context.

As Colin Fine points out, one could also ask a question silently using sign language. This should be obvious in context, as the telepathic communication would also be obvious; it depends on the themes and characters in the book.

It is conceivable that a writer could use it in a "messaging" or "texting" situation, but it would not be common or obvious usage. Instead they would simply use "asked [over text]."

Comment: While the first two entries on that page might be so, subsequent entries (like this one - https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/No_Such_Thing_as_Immortality/EvJJDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22asked+silently%22&pg=PT240&printsec=frontcover) imply that the words are being spoken out loud. I do understand your point about it being mental communication.

Comment: @user96551, if the novel has not previously established that the character can communicate telepathically, then I would say it is an editing error. The author likely means Madeline asked *very quietly* or *under her breath* or *timidly*. I haven't read the whole book so I can't be sure.

Comment: Fair enough. I came across that phrase in a different book (not sci-fi and no telepathy involved) and it kinda stumped me. I searched in google and found it to be used so I was even more confused.